# Deselect TreeView item after collapse

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView that looks like this:

```
Section1
  item1
  item2
Section2
  item1
  item2
```

In my project the "Section" elements should never be able to be selected so in my xaml I have disabled it like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
     <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="{Binding HasDetails}"/>
     </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This works great, I am able to select the "item" elements but not the "Section" elements. My problem is when I have an "item" selected and then collapse the "Section", the "Section" element gets selected. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Selected event (Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.selected.aspx) on the TreeViewItem.

When this event fires for Section1 or Section2, you can set the IsSelected property (Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isselected.aspx) on the TreeViewItem to false.

You can also use the SelectedItemChanged event (Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged.aspx) on the TreeView itself to unselect specific items when they are selected.

Make sure you unsubscribe before you set the IsSelect property, otherwise the event may fire multiple times. And don't forget to re-subscribe to the event after you set the IsSelect property.

Edit: Or even better, use the Collapsed event (Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.collapsed.aspx) that is on the TreeViewItem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I ended up binding the IsSelected property to a bool in my model and setting that to false.